# How do i point a propertyvaluefactory to a value of a map?

Tags: java, dictionary, properties, javafx, tableview

Instead of pointing a propertyvaluefactory to a property of an object as follows:

```
traineeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("sumName"));
```

I need it to point to a property inside a map, the map in turn is a property of the object it already is pointing to in the code above.
Is this possible?

edit: added code of the object in question.
So basically, i need the PropertyValueFactory to point toward the Integer with given key, the key  being the column header.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package models;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import database.DAO;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * @author Jasper
 */
public class Trainee {
    private final StringProperty firstName;
    private final StringProperty tussenVoegsel;
    private final StringProperty lastName;
    private final StringProperty branch;
    private final StringProperty sumName;
    private final Map<String, Integer> trainingPassed;

    public Trainee(String firstName, String tussenVoegsel, String lastName, String branch)
    {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.tussenVoegsel = new SimpleStringProperty(tussenVoegsel);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.branch = new SimpleStringProperty(branch);
        trainingPassed = new DAO().loadTrainingPassed(lastName);

        this.sumName = new SimpleStringProperty(this.firstName.get() + " " +
                this.tussenVoegsel.get() + " " + this.lastName.get());
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public String getTussenVoegsel() {
        return tussenVoegsel.get();
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public String getBranch() {
        return branch.get();
    }

    public String getSumName() {
        return sumName.get();
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getTrainingPassed() {
        return trainingPassed;
    }

}
```

Edit2: Added code area of tableview, including declarations etc.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private TableView table() {
        TableView tableCourseCategories = new TableView();
        ArrayList<TableColumn> colList = new ArrayList<>();

        TableColumn traineeCol = new TableColumn("Training");
        traineeCol.setMinWidth(130);
        traineeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("sumName"));

        for (Course course : courses) {
            if (course.getCategory().equals(this.category)) {
                TableColumn<Trainee, Number> tc = new TableColumn<>();
                tc.setEditable(true);
                tc.setMinWidth(130);
                tc.setText(course.getName());

//                tc.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Trainee>>, ObservableValue<Number>>() {
//                    @Override
//                    public ObservableValue<Number> call(CellDataFeatures<Trainee> data) {
//                        Integer value = data.getValue().getTrainingPassed().get("sumName");
//                        return new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(value);
//                    }
//                });

                colList.add(tc);
            }
        }

        tableCourseCategories.getItems().addAll(this.trainees);
        tableCourseCategories.getColumns().add(traineeCol);
        tableCourseCategories.getColumns().addAll(colList);

        return tableCourseCategories;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not suppress the "unchecked" warnings: there's no reason not to properly type your `TableView` and `TableColumn`s.

The `setCellValueFactory(...)` method in `TableColumn` does not need to take a `PropertyValueFactory`: it can take any `Callback<CellDataFeatures<S>, ObservableValue<T>>`. Here `S` is the type of data displayed by each row of the table (i.e. you are using a `TableView<S>`), and `T` is the type of data displayed in this column (i.e. you are using a `TableColumn<S,T>`). In your case `S` is `Trainee` and `T` is `Number`.

This `Callback` is essentially just a function that converts a given row value (Trainee in your case) to the value to be displayed in the cell. It's made slightly more complex in that the row value is wrapped in a `CellDataFeatures` object, and the return type is required to be an `ObservableValue` wrapping the actual value to be displayed. A `CellDataFeatures` is provided in case you want access to other information to calculate your value (it gives you access to the `TableColumn` in which the value is being displayed and the `TableView` in which the `TableColumn` is held). An `ObservableValue` is required to be returned as the `TableCell` will observe the value for changes and update automatically.

If you only want the row value, and don't care about knowing which `TableView` or `TableColumn` you are in (or already know, which is usual), you get the row value (the `Trainee` in your example) by calling `getValue()` on the `CellDataFeatures` object.

If you do not have an `ObservableValue` (e.g. a `Property`) for your value, you can wrap a regular value in one of the `ReadOnlyXXXWrapper` classes.

So basically all you need is a `Callback` implementation whose `call(...)` method computes the value to display from the value for the row.

In your example, the `call()` method just has to refer into the map:

```
traineeCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Trainee>, ObservableValue<Number>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Number> call(CellDataFeatures<Trainee> data) {
        Integer value = data.getValue().getTrainingPassed().get(course.getName());
        if (value == null) {
            value = 0 ;
        }
        return new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(value);
    }
});
```

In Java 8 this reduces to

```
traineeCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> 
    new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(data.getValue().getTrainingPassed().getOrDefault(course.getName(),0)));
```

The `PropertyValueFactory` which is used in many examples is just a pre-defined implementation that uses reflection to find an existing method in the supplied object that returns an observable value. The basic logic of what it does is outlined in the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html). IMHO it's pretty redundant in Java 8 as you can replace

```
firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
```

with

```
firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().firstNameProperty());
```

The latter is less error prone (everything is compiler-checked: the types of the method returns and the fact that such a method exists) as well as performing faster (reflection in general is pretty slow).

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help. The code is full of errors :c

Comment: What are the errors? You will probably have to update your question to show the declarations of the `TableView` and `TableColumn` as well.

Comment: I will, it gives errors about not enough type parameters (required 2) and some missing (); while im not sure where though cos the code seemed fine.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a typo (an extra `>`). Will fix.

Comment: OK, so I think that should work if you remove the additional `>`, and you need the map key to be `course.getName()`.

Comment: Thanks dude, it works! Could you care to explain a bit more in depth how this actually work? I don't just want to copy the code and use it without really understanding :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58974/discussion-between-taerus-and-james-d).