# Adding a CheckBox column to an existing TableView

Tags: javafx, checkbox, properties, boolean, tableview

I recently wanted to add a `CheckBox` column to an existing [`TableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html). To study the problem in isolation, I started with [*Example 13-6 Creating a Table and Adding Data to It*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#JFXUI271). I added a `BooleanProperty` and accessors to the `Person` model class, and I added a new `TableColumn` with a `CheckBoxTableCell` as the cell factory. As shown in the image, I see a `CheckBox` on each row. Although all values are `true`, none are checked; the checkboxes are live, but `setActive()` is never called. Recent [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bjavafx%5D%20TableView%20CheckBoxTableCell) on this topic suggest that I'm missing something; I'd welcome any insight.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Example 13-6 Creating a Table and Adding Data to It
 * https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE
 */
public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data
        = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(600);
        stage.setHeight(400);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Person, Boolean> active = new TableColumn<>("Active");
        active.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("active"));
        active.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(active));

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstName = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastName = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> email = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        email.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(active, firstName, lastName, email);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(8));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final BooleanProperty active;
        private final StringProperty firstName;
        private final StringProperty lastName;
        private final StringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.active = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public boolean getActive() {
            return active.get();
        }

        public void setActive(boolean b) {
            active.set(b);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String s) {
            firstName.set(s);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String s) {
            lastName.set(s);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String s) {
            email.set(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's a bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8235630

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68969222/adding-a-checkbox-column-to-an-existing-tableview?noredirect=1#comment121897521_68969223), this is an [unresolved issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8235630); see [*Why should I avoid using `PropertyValueFactory` in JavaFX?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72437983/230513) for more details; steps to avoid the pitfall include these:

- Verify that the data model exports properties correctly, as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD111).
- Critically examine the value of replacing `PropertyValueFactory` with an explicit `Callback`, when possible, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72437983/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050982/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25204271/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17037130/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65786210/230513).

The problem is that [`CheckBoxTableCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html) can't find or bind the `ObservableProperty<Boolean>` based on the parameter supplied:

```
active.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(active));
```

The `CheckBoxTableCell` defers to the table column for access to the target `Boolean` property. To see the effect, replace the `active` parameter with a [`Callback`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Callback.html) that returns the `ObservableValue<Boolean>` for row `i` explicitly:

```
active.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(
    (Integer i) -> data.get(i).active));
```

While this makes the checkboxes work, the underlying problem is that the `Person` class needs an accessor for the `active` property. [*Using JavaFX Properties and Binding*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD111) discusses the property method naming conventions, and the `Person` class of the [*Ensemble8* `tablecellfactory`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/apps/samples/Ensemble8/src/samples/java/ensemble/samples/controls/tablecellfactory) illustrates a working model class with a property getter for each attribute, also shown below.

With this change [`PropertyValueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html#PropertyValueFactory-java.lang.String-) can find the newly added `BooleanProperty`, and the original form of `forTableColumn()` works. Note that the convenience of [`PropertyValueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html#PropertyValueFactory-java.lang.String-) comes with some [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050982/230513). In particular, the factory's fall-through support for the previously missing property accessor goes unnoticed. Fortunately, the same accessor allows substitution of a simple `Callback` for each column's value factory. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25204271/230513), instead of `PropertyValueFactory`,

```
active.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("active"));
```

Pass a [lamda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax) that returns the corresponding property:

```
active.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().activeProperty());
```

Note also that `Person` can now be `private`. Moreover, the use of explicit type parameters affords stronger type checking during compilation.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/68969223/230513
 */
public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data
        = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(600);
        stage.setHeight(400);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Person, Boolean> active = new TableColumn<>("Active");
        active.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().activeProperty());
        active.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(active));

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstName = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstName.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().firstNameProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastName = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastName.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().lastNameProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, String> email = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        email.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().emailProperty());

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(active, firstName, lastName, email);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(8));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
        stage.show();
    }

    private static class Person {

        private final BooleanProperty active;
        private final StringProperty firstName;
        private final StringProperty lastName;
        private final StringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.active = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public BooleanProperty activeProperty() {
            return active;
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return email;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: good to suggest __not__ using PropertyValueFactory if we have full control over the data item :) On the other hand, not handling a ReadOnlyObjectPropertyWrapper (that's what returned from the factory if the bean prop is both readable and writable) correctly is a bug in CheckBoxXXCell https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8235630

Comment: Thanks for citing this helpful bug report; it surely _looks_ like a contradiction in the API. Please don't hesitate to edit this answer or add one of your own that elaborates. My goal was to post something fairly dispositive in the interim; I hate to guide others to the tutorial, only for them to confront a similar problem.