# CheckBoxTableCell Can't be selected on javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, checkbox, javabeans

New to JavaFx I created a view table  using Scene builder with a table column named **checkedCol** that's supposed to contain chekboxes , on my controller  i created those checkbox  this way  :

```
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.geometry.Insets;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
    import javafx.util.Callback;


     public class RecapController implements Initializable{

     @FXML
     private TableView<OMission> missionTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<OMission, Boolean> checkedCol; 

      private ObservableList<OMission> UserMission = 
 FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
      private OMission mission=null;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        
         
         
         try {
            load_recap();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
         
    }

    public void load_recap(){
    

      .....

     
    checkedCol.setCellFactory(
                                CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(checkedCol)
                            );
                        
    checkedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("remark"));

                    checkedCol.setEditable(true);


          }
          }
```

On class Model i have this code :

```
    public class OMission {

         private String ObjMission ;
         private Boolean remark;

         public OMission(  String objMission ) {

                 This.objMission = ObjMission ;

                 remark = false;
                           
                                    }

        public Boolean getRemark() {
            return remark;
        }

        public void setRemark(Boolean remark) {
            this.remark = remark;
        }


        public String getObjMission() {
            return ObjMission;
        }



        public void setObjMission(String objMission) {
            ObjMission = objMission;
        }
```

}

fxml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="pan" prefHeight="740.0" prefWidth="1258.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.RecapController">
   <children>
      <JFXButton layoutX="16.0" layoutY="22.0" onAction="#OpenMission" style="-fx-background-color: #0A4969;" text="Ajouter une nouvelle mission : " textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </JFXButton>
      <TableView fx:id="missionTable" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="64.0" prefHeight="659.0" prefWidth="1226.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="612.5" text="RAPPORT DE MISSION">
                           <columns>
                                
                              
                              <TableColumn fx:id="local" prefWidth="100.0" text="Localité" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="objmission" prefWidth="243.0" text="Objet Mission" />
                              
                           </columns>
                        </TableColumn>
                    
            <TableColumn fx:id="checkedCol"  prefWidth="75.0" text="select" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
      <JFXButton layoutX="263.0" layoutY="25.0" onAction="#print_tab" text="print" />
      <CheckBox fx:id="SelectAll" layoutX="1154.0" layoutY="41.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Select All" />

   </children>
```

The problem is i don't get any erros but i can not even select/check the checkboxes i get on my view table , i can't figure out the issue :) any idea ? Thank's in advance .

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra I've edited the post, thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code is not clear if the `Tableview` is editable. Assuming the `TableView` is `missionTable`, try:

```
missionTable.setEditable(true);
```

Alternatively you can set the `Tableview` editable in your FXML by adding `editable="true"`:

```
<TableView fx:id="missionTable" editable="true" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="64.0" prefHeight="659.0" prefWidth="1226.0">
```

Comment: That's working, i didn't think that could be the problem, very helpful Thank you :)

Comment: I added a second alternative using FXML. Glad it helped ;)

Comment: Absolutely, can you tell me please how i can get the selected checkbox this way ?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the selected checkbox this way"?

Comment: I have a JFXButton inside my fxml code , i want to get when i click on it, All the rows that were selected ( checkbox = true ) by the user

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for that (I'll try to answer it there).

Comment: Okey Thank you for your help and time :))

Comment: @dEs12ZER: As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68969222/230513), a working checkbox column updates the model, so your button handler can iterate over the table's `ObservableList`.