# How to add a checkbox into a TableView Column Cell for a ToDo List

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I am working with JavaFX and SceneBuilder, i created a TableView in SceneBuilder with 2 Columns, one for the task and is supposed to be a checkbox that the user can check when he did a task.

I'm also adding the Table to a MySql Database and initializing the values of the databank when the user starts the application. everything works fine with the initializing, the task shows on start, but i can't figure out how to add a checkbox to the column cell and how to initialize it then on start.

```
package org.stephan.javafx_todolist;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.stephan.javafx_todolist.data.DBConnection;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Objects;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane mainPane;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Task> tvTaskTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, String> taskColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, Boolean> isDoneColumn;

    ObservableList<Task> tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    protected void onAddButtonClick() throws IOException {
        Stage stage = (Stage) mainPane.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("add-scene.fxml")));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() throws SQLException {
        tvTaskTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        taskColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("taskName"));
        isDoneColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("isDone"));
        DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javafx", "root", "");
        String query = "select * from todos";
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnection.dbUrl(), dbConnection.user(), dbConnection.password());
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                tasks.add(new Task(resultSet.getString("task"), false));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        tvTaskTable.setItems(tasks);

    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html) doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicat of [_Adding a CheckBox column to an existing TableView_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68969222/230513).

Comment: See also [_Why should I avoid using PropertyValueFactory in JavaFX?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72437983/230513)

Comment: If this is _not_ a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.