# How can I send the elements of the tableview to another tableview?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, scenebuilder, observablelist

Basically what I'm trying to do is, I create a type object with a name and attribute names (I tried to collect those attribute names in a tableview). Then I create items by selecting those types I created before. The Item object i create has its name,type and attribute names. What I want is, when I'm creating an item, I select a type. When I select that type, I want the tableview in item creating page to show selected types attribute names.[item creating page is something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxWEV.png)

I tried something like this. Those are my initialize method and creatType methods.
any suggestions?

```
    ObservableList<Types> list2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<Items> list3 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();



public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    typeAttributesNames.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Types, String>("typeAttributesNames"));
    this.itemAttrValue.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Items,String>("attributeValues"));
    typeAttrNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Types,String>("typeAttributesNames2"));
    attrNameTableView.setItems(list2);
    itemsAttrTableView.setItems(list3);

}
 public void createType(){
    ObservableList<Types> typesObservableList=list2;
    Types types= new Types(typesTextField.getText(),typesObservableList);
    types.getTypesTitledPane().setText(typesTextField.getText());
    typeTitledPaneVbox.getChildren().addAll(types.getTypesTitledPane());
    typeNameComboBox.getItems().addAll(typesTextField.getText());
    Types.typesArrayList.add(types);
    typesTextField.clear();

    typeNameComboBox.setOnAction(e ->
            typeAttrTableView.setItems(typesObservableList));

     attrNameTableView.getItems().clear();

}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Maybe a `FilteredList`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69711881/230513).